# Why the variable trigger throws exception?

Tags: c#, variables, triggers

I'm stuck in declaring a variable with a **trigger**. This trigger is fired whenever the value of the variable changes and the trigger mechanism is supposed to alter the value of another variable.

Below code compiles fine but throws **NullReferenceException** ([screenshot after exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/infr6.png)).

**file: Program.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace test {
    class Program {
        public static Active active = new Active();
        public static FormMain formMain = new FormMain();

        [STAThread]

        static void Main() {
            Application.Run(formMain);
        }
    }
}
```

**file: DataStruct.cs**

```
namespace test {
    public class Active {
        public string UserName {
            get {
                return (Program.formMain.labelUserName.Text);
            }
            set {
                Program.formMain.labelUserName.Text = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**file FormMain.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace test {
    class FormMain : Form {
        public Label labelUserName = new Label();

        public FormMain() {
            this.Controls.Add(labelUserName);
            Program.active.UserName = "User Name";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are trying to call into `FormMain` before it's actually been initialized, the overall design here is terrible. The model is coupled with the UI in multiple places & Needless use of `static` variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because when you are in the `FormMain` constructor, the static variable `Program.formMain` has not been initialized yet, because you are creating the `FormMain` object which with you want to initialize `Program.formMain`.

Update `labelUserName` directly instead.

Comment: Well, I've changed my original code a bit in order to save space. In the original code, FormMain opens another form (FormLogin) and updates the user name in the status strip after evaluating password. In stead of declaring a variable for the class `Active`, I've tried using it as a global variable (like `Active.UserName = "..."`) and that did not work either.